# Probability of third ball drawn

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

Having a box containing 15 red and 7 blue balls. We want to draw 3 balls at random by these conditions on each draw:

- If the ball is red you set it aside
- If the ball is blue put it back in

What is probability that the third draw is blue? (If you get a blue ball it counts as a draw even though you put it back in the box.)

Can I say by these rules?

We have three balls drawn the total possibility is the sum of:

- Both the first two balls are red
- Both the first two balls are blue
- The first ball is red and the second is blue
- The first ball is blue and the second is red.

Then for each case I can calculate the probability of blue ball at third draw.

$
P=\frac{15}{22}*\frac{14}{21}*\frac{7}{20}+\frac{7}{22}*\frac{7}{22}*\frac{7}{22}+\frac{7}{22}*\frac{15}{22}*\frac{7}{21}+\frac{15}{22}*\frac{7}{21}*\frac{7}{21}
$

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, this seems right.

Comment: Seems right. Combinations are b * (bb + br+rb+rr)